# Build ghostscript from source in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, ghostscript

I have installed ghostscript package version 9.05 from repository, but that version overlaps text in some PDF conversions. Tested locally with version 9.06 and all seems ok.

I'm converting PDF files to jpg.

Now what i want to know is that when i compile and install ghostscript from source (9.10 version) do i need also copy some fonts to some directory? I have installed GS from source before but then i had some issues with fonts..

I have read this page, but didn't help me at all: http://ghostscript.com/doc/7.07/Make.htm#Unix_build

If i'm right the repository version handles all of these default font stuff automatically..

Is it possible to just replace package version gs -file with manually compiled version (rename and copy over) so all other settings like default fonts remains as they are from package (repository) version. Without uninstalling the package version..

Any other good, quality programs for command line patch converting PDF pages to JPG/PNG? Tested already imagemagic too but it's 10 times slower than GS.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest looking at Ubuntu's ghostscript package (apt-get source ghostscript) and see how the directories and config flags are setup there. Often it is easier to upgrade the package to a newer source and build a proper debian package, rather than trying to manually configure the package build system to tie in flawlessly with the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the entire Ghostscript source tree and build it using configure, it should all work perfectly well. Its unlikely that a self-compiled version will have the same settings as a packaged version, but anything which relies on environment will be unaffected by replacing the packaged version.

I'd suggest that you simply try it, if you have problems you can use IRC (irc.freenode.net, the #ghostscript channel) to talk to the developers.

Comment: Thanks, I have build that version (9.10) before, but then i had issues with some pdf.. gs hanged in some cases to font substitution.. with message something like "finding font for substitution" etc. That's why i think i have to manually copy some fonts? The pdf had all fonts embedded..

Comment: If the PDF file had all the fonts embedded, then you need do nothing with fonts as GS will always use the embedded fonts in preference to any others. You (should) never need to copy fonts, however, if you have set up GS incorrectly you could end up with *no* fonts available which conceivably might trigger such a problem. Note that the standard fonts are supplied in the source and so you should not have a problem with font substitution. I'm not the build expert, but as I said, try it and contact us if you have specific problems.

Comment: I found that there was just a bug in version 9.10. I installed the DEV version (9.11) and everything is working nicely! Thanks for help.